# Is there an easy way to create a logout button in the drawer in React Navigation V2?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, drawer

I want to have logout button in my drawer. The problem is that it should not render a screen, but just straight up log out. Is there a easy way to do it (e.g. somehow modifying the `contentOptions`' `items` or `onItemPressed` property? I couldn't figure something out.

What I'm doing right now is writing a `CustomDrawerComponent` with a logout button in it, but it's pretty hard to get the styling right and look alike the other `DrawerItems`.

Comment: what do you mean by "it should not render a screen", don't you want it to be redirected to your login flow?

Comment: @Deepak Yes I want it to redirect to my Login Screen. But besides that it should also log the user out, meaning it should perform some additional logic like clearing the token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved this with a custom component. Maybe there is a different way?

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Image, ScrollView, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { DrawerItems, SafeAreaView } from "react-navigation";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { clearToken } from "../../api/secureStorage/secureStorage";
import { BUTTON_TEXT_LOGOUT } from "../../config/constants/buttonTexts";
import { logout } from "../../redux/actions/logout/logout";
import styles from "./styles";

export class BurgerMenu extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.object,
    logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  logout = () => {
    const { navigation, logout } = this.props;
    clearToken().then(() => {
      logout();
      navigation.navigate("LoginScreen");
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { logout, ...strippedProps } = this.props; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} forceInset={{ top: "always", horizontal: "never" }}>
        <ScrollView>
          <DrawerItems {...strippedProps} />
        </ScrollView>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.footer, styles.item]} onPress={this.logout}>
          <Image
            source={require("../../assets/icons/exit.png")}
            style={styles.icon}
            resizeMode="contain"
          />
          <Text style={styles.text}>{BUTTON_TEXT_LOGOUT}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  { logout }
)(BurgerMenu);
```